# C# mysql beginners questions

Tags: c#, mysql, database

I want to make a program that enables a user to logon and see files stored on another PC. I have built a small program for a mechanic and now he's asking if I fancy making a service invoice system that stores invoices on his PC, and his customers can download a software that will filter out their invoices.

So I need to be able to connect to a pc from another pc and mysql was suggested.

I have never used mysql before and I have no idea how I am meant to start with this project.

Could I even do it through his website instead of a software? Just another idea...

Anyways, any help or pointers to beginners tuts on the web would be most helpful, thanks.

Comment: Maybe don't take the project and focus on what you currently do

Comment: And especially your customer should stay away from this unless you both are after getting a lot of trouble.

Comment: I dont really do anything programming-wise...I wanted to test my programming skills and ended up making an invoice software for him just for something to do/practice. He was impressed and asked if I would have a go at the invoice thing above. Im curious, how can I get into trouble? Got me worried now lol. Maybe I should have said the customer would only gain access to his own folder on the mechanics pc, not the entire C drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL works best and most safely when the MySQL server is on the same local-area network  and behind the same firewalls as the client software using it.

This means a local Windows desktop client (in C# as you have done) will work well.

But if your mechanic will have the server in his office (or in the cloud: in a commercial server farm someplace), and you will offer desktop software to his customers, that means the MySQL connection from HIS customers to his server will have to traverse firewalls.

That's going to make the desktop software hard to install and hard to troubleshoot. It's also going to make the MySQL server insecure: it will have to be able to accept connections from the global public network.  Script kiddies and cybercriminals love it when they find open MySQL database servers; copying the contents is child's play.

That is why most people who build applications like the one you propose build them as web applications. The connection to the database comes not from the end-user's machine, but from the web app. That web app runs on the same LAN and behind the same firewall as the MySQL server. You could build this web app in c# with modern .NET framework tools and get quite a nice result.

If the mechanic's customers will use a machine located in the waiting room, not at home, it's a different matter. A local Windows desktop app could work well.

Comment: Thanks for that. So a software based program wouldnt be a good idea then? I am better using a website as the customer would be accessing from his/her house, not within the mechanics premesis?

Comment: Exactly so. Client-server programs don't work well on the public internet.

Comment: Ok thanks. Will look into this more

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with C# you can use the mysql server to store and retrieve information. Just use the mysql connector from mysql website. There are tons of tutorials on how to use MySQL with C#.

Comment: I have had a look at various tutorials but found myself getting very lost, very quickly lol